# Jquery Animation failing initially in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a gallery that executes a series of animations when a thumbnail is clicked. One of those animations-- the resizing of the containing block-- works as expected in IE/Firefox, but fails initially in Safari, then works as expected on subsequent clicks. A gallery using a similar script on the "Installations" page of the site suffers from the same issue, only there it fails to ever calculate the correct width.

I've already tried switching from `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()` without success. I'm desperate for a solution; this project's been delayed because of this issue, and I'm not a developer so I don't have the first clue what could be going wrong. I'd be infinitely grateful for any help.

[Here's a link to the live site](http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/textiles/). The code in question is below:

```
$(window).load(function() {
            $('#back').hide();
            $('#full-wrap').hide();
            $('#thumb-wrap a').children().not('img').hide();//hide image captions

            var moveIt = $('#thumb-wrap').outerWidth(); //Get the width of the thumb-wrap div
            /*if ($.browser.webkit) {
                    var moveIt = $('#thumb-wrap').css({width: '100%'});
                    $('#full-wrap').width(383);
                }*/

            $('#thumb-wrap a').click(function(){

                var $big = $(this).index(); //get 0-based index of the thumb that was just clicked
                $('#ajax-content > h1').hide();//hide the page title
                $('#thumb-wrap').hide(); //hide the thumbnails
                $(this).children().not('img').clone().appendTo($('#gallery-wrap')).wrapAll('<div class="article"/>').delay(600).fadeIn(); //Clone the image captions and wrap them in an article
                $('#back').fadeIn(500); //make the back button appear

                $('#full-wrap img').eq($big).siblings().hide(); //Hide all fullsized images that don't match the index of the clicked thumb
                $('#full-wrap img').eq($big).show(); //reveal fullsized image that does match the index of the clicked thumbnail


                $('#content').animate({'maxWidth': '+=' + moveIt * 0.5 + 'px', 'left': '6%'}, 'slow');
                $('#full-wrap').show(100).animate({ 'right': '+=' + moveIt * 0.75 + 'px'}, 'slow'); //slide out by a distance equal to the width of thumb-wrap.

            });

            $('#back').click(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut();//hide the back button
                $('.article').remove();//remove the article div
                $('#full-wrap').animate({'right': '0', 'opacity' : 'toggle'}, 400);//hide the fullsize image div
                $('#content').animate({'maxWidth': moveIt, 'left' : '43%'}, 400);
                $('#thumb-wrap').delay(500).fadeIn(500);//reveal the thumbnails
                $('#ajax-content > h1').delay(500).fadeIn(100);//show the page title

            });

         });


<div id="gallery-wrap">
    <a href="#" id="back"><h3>Back</h3></a>
    <div id="thumb-wrap">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/11t.jpg" alt="DC1F" />
            <h1>DC1F</h1>
            <p>Material: Merino wool, raw silk, silk gauze, cashmere, wild silk, raw linen and silk yard.</p>

        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/6t.jpg" alt="DC2F" />
            <h1>DC2F</h1>
            <p>Material: Merino wool, silk organza, and wild silk.</p>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/10t.jpg" alt="DC3F" />

            <h1>DC3F</h1>
            <p>Material: Silk organza, merino wool, handspun wool and silk, and raw silk. Dyed with color derived from weld.</p>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/8t.jpg" alt="DC4F" />
            <h1>DC4F</h1>
            <p>Material: Merino wool, silk organza, raw silk, raw linen, and Wensleydale wool. Dyed with color derived from onion skins. </p>

        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/18t.jpg" alt="DC5F" />
            <h1>DC5F</h1>
            <p></p>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/9t.jpg" alt="DC6F" />

            <h1>DC6F</h1>
            <p>Material: Merino wool, silk chiffon, raw silk, and raw linen.</p>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/22t.jpg" alt="DC7F" />
            <h1>DC7F</h1>
            <p>Material: Natural yak hair, merino wool, raw silk, and handspun silk.</p>

        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/23t.jpg" alt="DC9F" />
            <h1>DC9F</h1>
            <p>Material: Merino wool, raw silk, silk organza, and raw linen.
Dyed with color derived from weld.</p>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/19t.jpg" alt="DC10F" />

            <h1>DC10F</h1>
            <p>Material: Merino wool, silk chiffon, and raw silk. Yellow is dyed with color derived from weld.</p>
        </a>
    </div>
        <div id="full-wrap">
            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/11.jpg" alt="DC1F" />

            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/6.jpg" alt="DC2F" />

            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/10.jpg" alt="DC3F" />


            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/8.jpg" alt="DC4F" />

            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/18.jpg" alt="DC5F" />

            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/9.jpg" alt="DC6F" />

            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/22.jpg" alt="DC7F" />

            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/23.jpg" alt="DC9F" />

            <img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/19.jpg" alt="DC10F" />
    </div>
```

Comment: actually it works in my Safari 5.0.4, or I just misunderstood your problem?

Comment: The animation does execute, but not to the correct width initially. Here's a screenshot from Firefox so you can see what I mean. http://i53.tinypic.com/i2ow7s.jpg This is the same width that the gallery on the `Installations` page should be animating to as well.

Comment: http://img826.imageshack.us/i/safarix.png/ this is my screenshot on Safari, I don't see differences.

Comment: @linmic Strange. Here's how it looks on initial click in 5.0.4 on PC and the Mac in our office: http://i56.tinypic.com/10fur2g.jpg The installations page looks that way as well. Does the installations page expand to full length for you as well when a thumbanil is clicked? http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/installations/

Comment: @linmic No, that's good if it's working for the web at large-- I just don't understand why it's showing that way on our end. The client didn't mention it, so I'm going to guess it didn't show up incorrectly for him either. What OS are you running?

Comment: Currently using Windows 7 x64 here.

Comment: @linmic Hm. I'm running Windows XP, and the Mac is OSX. If it were isolated to OSX I'd just wash my hands of it, but I can't figure out why it's failing on Safari in XP AND OSX. Can you think of any known safari issues that might cause this?

Comment: OS does matters, there are tons of factors which may result in differences. So I would suggest you to leave it to your client, they will report to you if they don't feel good about it :P

Comment: @linmic Oh trust me, if it were up to the client I'd be done by now. Because it's not appearing correctly on the office Mac my boss wants me to fix it, but I can't fix something that's not actually wrong! At this point I think I'll just have to point out that the site's optimized and working for the largest market share.

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling, I went with the sledgehammer solution: I used `if ($.browser.webkit)` to feed Safari pixel widths for the block elements vs. percents as in the css. And now it works! And that's good enough for me. :)